# Disable toolbar scrolling

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout, androiddesignsupport, android-appbarlayout

I have the current setup:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordiator_layout_in_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    <FrameLayout
        // I place a fragment containing a viewpager containing    fragments that contain a recyclerview.... 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nav_view">

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/settings_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/coordiator_layout_in_main"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"   
   app:layout_behavior="com.material.widget.MyFloatingActionButtonBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now everything work as expected if I scroll inside the framelayout that contains the fragments, the toolbar slides in and out as I want

Now the point is that I would like to **disable the toolbar sliding in and out if I scroll the NavView** which is on the side of the framelayout (and inside the relativelayout)

But no matter if I remove all scrolling behaviors the toolbar keeps on sliding in and out (only way to disable it is remove the scroll flags form the appbarlayout, but that disable all sliding in and out of the tolbar)

Please what am I missing here? Aren't the scolling behaviours supposed to pass the scroll events to the CoordinatorLayout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, `NavigationView` contains `NavigationMenuView` which is `RecyclerView` and so it supports nested scrolling and moves `AppBarLayout` when scrolled. The best way to solve this problem would be to move `NavigationView` out of `CoordinatorLayout`. If it's not possible you can try the following code, which I haven't tested.

```
final RecyclerView navigationMenuView =
    (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.design_navigation_view);
navigationMenuView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Please take into account that even if this code works it can break when the Design library is updated.

Answer (score 6):

Move your NavigationView inside a DrawerLayout and the CoordinatorLayout inside the main content of the DrawerLayout.

From docs:

> NavigationView is typically placed inside a DrawerLayout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

 <!-- Your contents -->

 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

try this,

Put this activity_screen.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_screen" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home_screen"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/app_theme_color"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_screen_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Put this app_bar_screen.xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.test.app.HomeScreenActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_screen" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Put this content_screen.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home_screen"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context="com.test.app.HomeScreenActivity">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should comment or annotate your code to help with comprehension. Otherwise this just leads to copy paste developers.

Comment: yes right i but didn't gave any answer without any test .But thank for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line of code`app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` from your `ToolBar`. Worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who might be interested this is how I dealt with the issue.

I created my custom version of the NavigationView by copying the relevant files form the source,

they are:

- NavigationView.java
- NavigationMenuItem.java
- NavigationMenuPresente.java
- NavigationMenuView.java
- ThemeUtils.java

Fix the imports so that the new NavigationView points to the newly copied files.

And finally add this `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` to the constructor of `NavigationMenuView`.

This is because, how @Michael correctly pointed out the `NavigationMenuView` is a RecyclerView, and as such it passes its scrolling events to the `NestedScrollingParent` (the CoordinatorLayout), by setting `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` we disable this behaviour and we get the desired result (scrolling the NavView does not expand/collapse the AppBar)